# right click values for Gridview column

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-3.5

I have grid named 'GridView1'  and displaying columns like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowCommand="ScheduleGridView_RowCommand" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="60px"
    Style="text-align: center" Width="869px" EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Topic" DataField="Topic" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Moderator" HeaderText="Moderator" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expert" HeaderText="Expert" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EndTime" HeaderText="End" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="175px" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Join" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="JoinBT" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="Join" Text="Join" Width="52px" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Height="15px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here what is my requirement is whenever we right click on each row in gridview ,it should display three option join meeting(if we click it will go to
meeting.aspx),,view details(will go to detail.aspx),,Subscribe(subscribe.aspx)   just like when we click right any where we can see view,sortby,refresh

like that..Do we need to implement **javascript** here